# Routing to more than one action

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I want to route to more than one action, I make the routing configuration on application.ini file.

```
resources.router.routes.blog.route = /blogs
resources.router.routes.blog.defaults.module = blogs
resources.router.routes.blog.defaults.controller = blog
resources.router.routes.blog.defaults.action = index


resources.router.routes.blog.route = /blogs/add
resources.router.routes.blog.defaults.module = blogs
resources.router.routes.blog.defaults.controller = blog
resources.router.routes.blog.defaults.action = add
```

When I make like this, the default routing /blogs return error

```
Message: Invalid controller specified (index)

 array (
  'module' => 'blogs',
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your routes have the same name, adjust your routes to something similar to:

```
//the 4th parameter is the name of the route and needs to be unique for each different route
resources.router.routes.blogs.route = /blogs
resources.router.routes.blogs.defaults.module = blogs
resources.router.routes.blogs.defaults.controller = blog
resources.router.routes.blogs.defaults.action = index


resources.router.routes.blogsadd.route = /blogs/add
resources.router.routes.blogsadd.defaults.module = blogs
resources.router.routes.blogsadd.defaults.controller = blog
resources.router.routes.blogsadd.defaults.action = add
```